# how to run the android application in device?

Tags: android, apk

i have android device, how can i run the application connecting with my system instead running in the emulator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Connect your device via USB to your computer:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

And then adb should use preferentially the hardware device over the emulator.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-eclipse.html

> **Automatic and manual target modes**
>
> By default, a run configuration uses
>   the **automatic** target mode in order to
>   select an AVD. In this mode, ADT will
>   select an AVD for the application in
>   the following manner:
>
> 1) If there's a device or emulator already running and its AVD
>   configuration meets the requirements
>   of the application's build target, the
>   application is installed and run upon
>   it.
>
> 2) If there's more than one device or emulator running, each of which meets
>   the requirements of the build target,
>   a "device chooser" is shown to let you
>   select which device to use.
>
> 3) If there are no devices or emulators running that meet the
>   requirements of the build target, ADT
>   looks at the available AVDs. If there
>   is an AVD that matches the build
>   target of the project, ADT chooses
>   that AVD. If the AVD versions are
>   newer than the build target of the
>   project, ADT chooses the oldest
>   possible version of an AVD that meets
>   the project's build target
>   requirement.
>
> 4) If there are no suitable AVDs, the application is not installed a console
>   error warning tells you that there is
>   no existing AVD that meets the build
>   target requirements.
>
> However, if a "preferred AVD" is
>   selected in the run configuration,
>   then the application will always be
>   deployed to that AVD. If it's not
>   already running, then a new emulator
>   will be launched.
>
> If your run configuration uses **manual**
>   mode, then the "device chooser" is
>   presented every time that your
>   application is run, so that you can
>   select which AVD to use.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Via ide plugin. Eclipse and IDEA both are able to lauch and debug applications on the real devices, only thing you need is the driver installed for your mobile.
2. Via apk. Just make an apk, copy it to sdcard, and install it from your device using some file manager like ASTRO.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in another way. Attached your .apk file and mail it to your mail account. Then login to your account(account that you send the .apk file) on device, download the .apk file and install it on your device.

Comment: does this work? I'm going to test it tonight and if it does I will upvote your answer...