# Android Open 3GLES running error

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am running my Android application but Open 3GLES shows some error can you guide me what is the problem.Error is

```
03-27 12:11:22.822: W/dalvikvm(486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486): java.lang.Error: OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supported by this device
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at rajawali.RajawaliActivity.onCreate(RajawaliActivity.java:25)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at com.rozengain.rajawali.ui.RajawaliUserInterfaceActivity.onCreate(RajawaliUserInterfaceActivity.java:13)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-27 12:11:22.842: E/AndroidRuntime(486):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks pretty clear to me

`java.lang.Error: OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supported by this device`

What device are you using, or are you using the emulator? Emu doesn't support GLES2.0 if I recall correctly.

Comment: ya we are using andriod 2.3.3 emulator.. can you tell which emulator support the openGLES??

Comment: @ASR I don't think any API level supports OPENGL2.0. I think they support 1.0 though.

Comment: As of now support for GL2.0 is not added to emulator. Run the code in a device and check.

Comment: @tim i made my application in 2.3.3 can we run it on 1.6

Comment: @user936414 how to run on device ?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819195/how-to-run-the-android-application-in-device