# absolute beginner opening my first app in eclipse, what file to open

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I know this is a real silly question but I am following the instructions to create an app for android. Im currently here... http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html 
Ive already set up my first app as per instuctions, Ive enabled debugging on my phone, but now Im unsure what file to open in eclipse before clicking "Run as"-> "Android Application".
Any help would be great thanks

Comment: any of your projects files should be fine.

Comment: thanks, just one other question, when I run as "android application", nothing happens on my phone, even though I have enabled debugging. Theres no indication that anything is getting installed. Any ideas?

Comment: check my answer below. I'm pretty sure Eclipse doesn't recognize your device. You should install the appropriate drivers and restart Eclipse

Comment: you can check my answer to run on real device

Comment: as Maver1ck suggested, you must have the correct drivers installed to test code on your device, google <your device model> usb android development drivers (or something like that) and you should be able to find what you need.

Comment: thank you, Ill try to find the correct drivers, I assumed the drivers were already installed ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open or close any file(s) for running the app, just make sure the project you want to run is selected in the project explorer on the left side. But I assume that you only have one project at this time so everything should work as expected

**EDIT**

If you want to test your app on a real device from Eclipse, make sure the required device drivers are installed. You can go to `Run -> Run Configurations -> target` and check if your device is listed. In case that is not, some drivers are missing.

Comment: thanks, fwiw for anyone else reading, installing samsung kies was enough to find the correct drivers

Answer (score 0):

Select your `MainActivity` and click run. It will prompt a box where you can choose weather you want to run in device or in emulator.

To run in real device See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422294/how-to-run-the-android-app-on-real-device/12422475#12422475). It will help you.